# Neo4j Cypher: Return a list of distinct edge types with number of occurences

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-databases

I know I can return all distinct edge types like so:

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
RETURN distinct(type(r))
```

How can I return each distinct type along with the number of occurrences?

Answer (score 1):

```
match ()-[r]->() return type(r),count(*)
```

Comment: While this is technically correct in that you will eventually get the right answer, this query does not use the counts store to derive the answer. If you EXPLAIN this query, you'll see it does an AllNodesScan, then expands all relationships from all nodes, then does an aggregation based on the type. This type of query won't scale well as nodes and relationships increase.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type, you can make a query using the counts store which is instant.

```
MATCH ()-[r:ACTED_IN]->()
RETURN count(r) as count
```

Unfortunately relationship types aren't dynamic in Cypher, you can't specify them via parameters or string values (as a result of your previous query, for example).

If you have [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/), there's a procedure that will quickly get you exactly what you want, however, a piece of data from the `apoc.meta.stats()` call.

```
CALL apoc.meta.stats() YIELD relTypesCount 
RETURN relTypesCount
```